# Can't curl linked container in Docker even though I can ping it

Tags: linux, django, curl, docker, gunicorn

I have a Docker container called backend that exposes a port, 8200, and runs a django server behind gunicorn inside of it.  This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y -q \
                    curl \
                    procps \
                    python=2.7.3-4+deb7u1 \
                    git \
                    python-pip=1.1-3 \
                    python-dev \
                    libpq-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}

RUN pip install virtualenv && \
    virtualenv mockingbird && \
    /bin/bash -c "source mockingbird/bin/activate"

ADD ./requirements.txt /mockingbird/backend/requirements.txt
RUN /mockingbird/bin/pip install -r /mockingbird/backend/requirements.txt

ADD ./src /mockingbird/backend/src

CMD ["/mockingbird/bin/gunicorn", "--workers", "8", "--pythonpath", "/mockingbird/backend/src/", "--bind", "localhost:8200", "backend.wsgi"]
```

I'm running this container like so:

```
vagrant@10:~$ sudo docker run --name backend --env-file /mockingbird/apps/backend/env/dev -d --restart always --expose 8200 mockingbird/backend
```

I know that the django server is up and responding on the correct port by doing the following and getting a response:

```
vagrant@10:~$ sudo docker exec -it backend /bin/bash
root@b488874c204d:/# curl localhost:8200
```

I then start a new container linking to backend as follows:

```
sudo docker run -it --link backend:backend debian:wheezy /bin/bash
```

But when I try to curl backend, it doesn't work:

```
root@72946da3dff9:/# apt-get update && apt-get install curl
root@72946da3dff9:/# curl backend:8200
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I am, however, able to ping backend:

```
root@72946da3dff9:/# ping backend
PING backend (172.17.0.41): 48 data bytes
56 bytes from 172.17.0.41: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
56 bytes from 172.17.0.41: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
```

Anyone know anything else I can try to debug why I can't connect to the service running in my linked Docker container?  Is there something I am missing here to be able to curl backend:8200 from the linked container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this might be a problem: `"--bind", "localhost:8200"` as connections to `backend` hostname won't be accepted. You might want to change it to `"0.0.0.0:8200"` or maybe `":8200"`, depending on the notation supported.

Comment: @Mykola Gurov :I am facing same problem in docker-compose, although I have exposed the required ports.

Comment: I'm in the same boat also. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I wanted to alias varnish as `api.localhost.com` but when I curl it from another container it won't, because curl was using `80`, because I thought that `80` is the port I was exposing, but when you are inside the container and you want to use the alias, you should use the port that is listening inside the varnish container which was `6081` and not the exposed one, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your application is listening on the loopback address `0.0.0.0` rather than `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

In my case, it was a compose of two containers: golang http app & mongodb. While I was able to ping my app from the mongodb container, I wasn't able to curl it.

**Courtesy**: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/16o8wwv/comment/k1jblv9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button